# Firestore Security Rule Get in Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following rule which works:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /item/{itemId} {
    allow read:get(/databases/$(database)/documents/properties/$(resource.data.propertyId)).data.users[request.auth.uid] == true)
  }
}
```

I would like to make this a function such as:

```
function isPropertyMember() {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/properties/$(resource.data.propertyId))
  .data.users[request.auth.uid] == true
}
```

allow read: if isPropertyMember()

With the same query from the same user data is returned on the query when not in the function. When I move it to the function I get "Missing or insufficient permission" error.

Comment: What exactly does not work?  Please be specific.  Also you should edit the question to show the entire, minimal set of rules that you're working with, not just one line or one function.

Comment: @DougStevenson updated. hopefully this provides more info

Comment: @ChrisMancini Please add the entire rules with code (in particular the relative position of the code blocks).

Comment: Did you test this in the rules simulator in the Firebase console?  It will give you more details on what might be going wrong.

Comment: I figured this out...my function is outside of the scope of the match so I had to pass the database variable into the function.Thanks @DougStevenson

Comment: That's why I was recommending that you show the entire set of rules.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am new to the firestore rules so I really didnt understand what your were talking about. Now I'm aware and will post them in the future. Thanks.

Comment: The general rule for Stack Overflow is to always post a minimal, complete, verifiable example [(MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it's easy for anyone to reproduce the problem on their end.